# Swift iOS - UITableView Custom Cell not appearing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate my tableView with a custom cell - seems pretty straight forward, but for some reason when I run the following code, the custom cell doesn't appear? I feel like I'm missing something super obvious.

**Custom cell name is:** OffersTableViewCell

**DashboardViewController**

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        
        self.registerTableViewCells()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableViewCell") as? OffersTableViewCell {
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    private func registerTableViewCells() {
        let textFieldCell = UINib(nibName: "OffersTableViewCell",
                                  bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(textFieldCell,
                                forCellReuseIdentifier: "OffersTableViewCell")
    }
    
 

}
```

**OffersTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class OffersTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var offerTitle: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What's the frame of `tableView`?

Comment: Have you tried adding NumbersOfSections function at datasource? Also, have you tried reloadData()? Might wanna share us your code with custom cell file.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt`.  Does it get called?  If so, does it choose the correct type of cell?

Comment: Threw a breakpoint there and yes, cellForRowAt does get called, as does the correct cell. I tried putting self.tableView.reloadData() into viewDidLoad as well, still nothing. @PhillipMills

Comment: @Brittany - We assume you have something in your cell xib to display, since you're not setting anything in `cellForRowAt`? Also, you say `cellForRowAt` *does* get called... but does it make it into your `if let cell =` line? And, why are you doing that to begin with?

Comment: @Brittany why don't you share the code of the `OffersTableViewCell`? Is it done via storyboard? Could you try using print statement or breakpoint to check if the line `return cell` gets called?

Comment: See tableviewcell code above. Done in storyboard. @Michael

Comment: @Brittany - change this: `if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableViewCell") as? OffersTableViewCell { return cell }` to this: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableViewCell` ... if you get an error, then you haven't setup / registered your cell xib correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to resolve the issue by using the code below. I would suggest we remove UITableViewCell().

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        
        self.registerTableViewCells()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableViewCell 
        return cell
        //put any other exception conditions to display UITableViewCell() if necessary
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: This throws me error: Value of optional type 'OffersTableViewCell?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'OffersTableViewCell' on the 'return cell' line.

Comment: I added `, for: indexPath` on the dequeReusableCell, could you try again?

Comment: Using a question mark here: `as? OffersTableViewCell` makes it **optional** -- which is wrong.

Comment: So weird. I literally just created a new custom cell, and now it works. NO idea why. Been reading that's the case for a few people on stack. Wth lol.

Comment: That's great! Unfortunately, I cannot comment further because I would only know the exact reasons if I have full details/storyboard itself. Good luck with your work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Try to go through these steps:

1. Check if **.xib** file named as **OffersTableViewCell.xib**
   [image]
2. Check if File's Owner class is `OffersTableViewCell`
   [image]
3. Make sure you deleted default view in **.xib** and created `UITableViewCell`
4. Check if class of cell is `OffersTableViewCell`
   [image]
5. Check if cell identifier is **OffersTableViewCell**
   [image]
6. Check if class of view controller in storyboard is `DashboardViewController`
7. Make sure you open `DashboardViewController` in app

Comment: The strangest. I literally just created a new custom cell, and now it works. NO idea why. Been reading that's the case for a few people on stack. Wth lol.

Comment: Haha, that's fine, sometimes strange things happen when coding) If you want I can check your old code and maybe find what a problem was, if you send me whole project